# iOS: step wise PayPal braintree integration

Tags: ios, objective-c, paypal, braintree

In my application i need to provide that, client should pay using credit cards. Paypal mobile SDK does not support it.

So i need to integrate Brain tree but nowhere i found proper steps to integrate it.

Can anyone one please help me to integrate paypal braintree in my application.

Comment: https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/hello-client/ios/v4

Comment: I believe the above link is more than enough

Comment: Thanks. I have gone through this link but i have some doubts like where to set payment amount and receivers detail. And at the server setup how to create url and from where the connection to paypal is established.

Answer (score 1):

Search the documentation for more details below!!

https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/paypal/client-side/ios/v4

```
#import "BraintreePayPal.h"

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

self.braintreeClient = [[BTAPIClient alloc] initWithAuthorization:@"<#CLIENT_AUTHORIZATION#>"];

UIButton *customPayPalButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 120)];
[customPayPalButton addTarget:self
                       action:@selector(customPayPalButtonTapped:)
             forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:customPayPalButton];
}


- (IBAction)customPayPalButtonTapped:(id)sender {
BTPayPalDriver *payPalDriver = [[BTPayPalDriver alloc] initWithAPIClient:self.braintreeClient];
payPalDriver.viewControllerPresentingDelegate = self;
payPalDriver.appSwitchDelegate = self; // Optional

// Start the Vault flow, or...
[payPalDriver authorizeAccountWithCompletion:^(BTPayPalAccountNonce *tokenizedPayPalAccount, NSError *error) {
    ...
}];

// ...start the Checkout flow
BTPayPalRequest *request = [[BTPayPalRequest alloc] initWithAmount:@"1.00"];  //Here you need to enter the amount 
[payPalDriver requestOneTimePayment:request
                        completion:^(BTPayPalAccountNonce *tokenizedPayPalAccount, NSError *error) {
    ...
}];
}
```

Comment: have you successfully done Braintree integration within any of your application?

Comment: Can you please guide me personally?

Comment: Sure,How can I help you

Comment: Thanks, Please let me know how can i contact you?

Comment: We are facing problem while setup of simple server. So can you help me in that

Comment: How can contact you ?

Comment: @radkrish While tapping on paypal from dropin UI no action is performed.

Comment: check whether you had implemented the delegate ?

Comment: @radkrish thank's for the step by step instruction's and i am facing problem while setup of  simple server setup ...can you guide me in that